# VB.net Translate any characters with an Ascii value less than 32, or greater than 126, to an empty string

Tags: vb.net, string, ascii, translation

How would I go about creating a vb.net function that accepts a string and replaces all non-printable characters (<32 or >126) with an empty string?

Comment: Use a StringBuilder and a For loop.  Surely you can take it from there?

Comment: Have you tried something like [regular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-11) [expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html)? Any code snippets you've tried can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could just go through the string character by character:

```
Private Function Convert(input As String) As String
    Dim asArray As Char() = input.ToCharArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To asArray.Length - 1
        If AscW(asArray(i)) < 32 OrElse AscW(asArray(i)) > 126 Then
            asArray(i) = " "C
        End If
    Next

    Return New String(asArray)
End Function
```

Comment: I like this approach because it avoids using StringBuilder.  This from the guy whose answer is usually "use a StringBuilder".

Comment: @NYCdotNet Normally, I'm all for StringBuilder, but... Since the string is a fixed length in input and output, this is actually going to be better than a string builder, and it's simpler IMO ;)

Comment: @user2868039  if this helped, click the checkmark next to the answer so this falls off there unanswered list

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It uses an array of legal characters, currently all of the Ascii values from 32-126.

```
Private Function convertChars(input As String) As String
    Const legalchars As String = " !""#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
    Dim rv As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each c As Char In input
        If legalchars.IndexOf(c) > 0 Then rv.Append(c)
    Next
    Return rv.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ as well:

```
    Dim startstring As String = "ferojifsdajknf" + Chr(0) + "sdiojufsda" + Chr(20) + "jikwfe"
    Dim result As String = Join((From c As Char In startstring                                     
                                Where Asc(c) >= 32 AndAlso Asc(c) <= 126
                                Let s = c.ToString
                                Select s).ToArray, "")

?startstring.ToCharArray
{Length=32}
    (0): "f"c
    (1): "e"c
    (2): "r"c
    (3): "o"c
    (4): "j"c
    (5): "i"c
    (6): "f"c
    (7): "s"c
    (8): "d"c
    (9): "a"c
    (10): "j"c
    (11): "k"c
    (12): "n"c
    (13): "f"c
    (14): "
    (15): "s"c
    (16): "d"c
    (17): "i"c
    (18): "o"c
    (19): "j"c
    (20): "u"c
    (21): "f"c
    (22): "s"c
    (23): "d"c
    (24): "a"c
    (25): ""c
    (26): "j"c
    (27): "i"c
    (28): "k"c
    (29): "w"c
    (30): "f"c
    (31): "e"c

?result.ToCharArray
{Length=30}
    (0): "f"c
    (1): "e"c
    (2): "r"c
    (3): "o"c
    (4): "j"c
    (5): "i"c
    (6): "f"c
    (7): "s"c
    (8): "d"c
    (9): "a"c
    (10): "j"c
    (11): "k"c
    (12): "n"c
    (13): "f"c
    (14): "s"c
    (15): "d"c
    (16): "i"c
    (17): "o"c
    (18): "j"c
    (19): "u"c
    (20): "f"c
    (21): "s"c
    (22): "d"c
    (23): "a"c
    (24): "j"c
    (25): "i"c
    (26): "k"c
    (27): "w"c
    (28): "f"c
    (29): "e"c
```